# Oracle: Timestamp when schema has been created?

Tags: sql, oracle, schema, creation

is there a possibility via SQL to get the timestamp when a schema (for example `SYS`) has been created?

Background:

Actually, I want to get the timestamp when I initially setup the whole DB cluster: I regularly delete and recreate it via `dbca` and import DB backups. So I'm interested when this process happend the last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the solution myself: `select created from all_users where username = 'someuser'` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This select gives you the creation date of the `V_$SESSION` `VIEW` from the current schema, which should also be your setup time.

```
select to_char(created, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
from   all_objects
where  object_name = 'V_$SESSION'
and    object_type = 'VIEW';
```

Comment: Hm, it seems that `V_$SESSION` is actually even older than the setup time of the DB cluster/schema. So this timestamp is unfortunately not the one, I am looking for. I will stick to `all_users` and filter for a username that has been created manually.